# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints error makes the screen flickers in IOS 9

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I am getting following log in my console in XCode.

```
2016-10-12 16:48:13.218 xx[319:19209] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16c610c0 H:[JTImageButton:0x16c61120'\Ufffc(null)'(130)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16be02a0 '_UITemporaryLayoutWidth' H:[JTImageButton:0x16c61120'\Ufffc(null)'(1000)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
```

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

And my screen flickers when this log happens.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving your `JTImageButton` a horizontal size of 130 and after that you are defining another constraint that set is horizontal size to 1000. Remove 1 of those constraints. You cannot define multiple size constraints for the same axis.

Comment: I do not add 1000. It is something that I don't know. _UITemporaryLayoutWidth was added and I don't know where.